# how to add link button in the listbox control in asp.net

Tags: c#-2.0

I want to add link button inside the listbox.....
For every item i want add one link button to display something which i want....

Answer (score 0):

Then I'd say that you don't want to use a listbox.
Surely a simple grid control would be more appropriate??

Comment: using this i need it..its is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] array1 = Directory.GetDirectories(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath+"Photo Galary");// so for each logical drive make this call

    // Display all folders.
    LinkButton btn;
    foreach (string name in array1)
    {
        btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.Text = name;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnclk_Click);
        ListBox2.Controls.Add(btn);

    }
}
public void btnclk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: please help me to do it properly